# Is to possible to receive callback when receive new email

Tags: php, cron, imap

I've one function which will catch emails with imap but the problem is whenever I receive new email I've to manually check or run cron for it to check it. is there any way that whenever I receive new email I receive any callback with it too so I'll call that function only when I know I receive email and stop running continuous cron.

I am using webmail and imap.

```
function read_emails()
    {        
        //load email reader class
        $this->load->model('upload_file_model');
        //delete media
        //$this->delete_all_attach();

        $this->load->library('Email_reader', array('UserName' => 'abcd@example.org', 'Password' => '12345678'));        
        //this will fetch emails as well all attachements
        $commentsData = $this->email_reader->catchEmails();

        if(isset($commentsData) && !empty($commentsData))
        {
            //$url = 'http://localhost/myproject/api/activity/addComment';
            foreach ($commentsData as $Data)
            {                
                //check if the entity exists in the system
                $IsEntityExists = get_detail_by_guid($Data['EntityGUID']);
                if($IsEntityExists)
                {
                   //Process attachment                
                   $media = $this->upload_file_model->uploadExternalAttachmnts($Data['Media']['attachments'],array('Sender'=>$Data['sender'],'Type'=>$Data['Type']));

                   //$attachmentData = array('qqfile'=>$Data['Media']['attachments'],'Type'=>$Data['Type'],'DeviceType'=>'native');

                   //calling uploadImage
                   //$media = $this->callAPI($attachmentData, SITE_URL.ROOT_FOLDER.'/api/upload_image');

                   //for requesting any api we need to send Login Sesion Key
                   $Data['LoginSessionKey'] = $this->session->userdata('LoginSessionKey');
                   if(!empty($media))
                   {
                       $Data['Media'] = array();
                       foreach ($media as  $md)
                          $Data['Media'][] = array('MediaGUID'=> $md,'Caption'=>'');
                   }
                   $Data['IsExternaCommunication'] = 1;

                   //calling comment  api
                   //$this->callAPI($Data, SITE_URL.ROOT_FOLDER.'/api/activity/addComment');
                   ExecuteCurl($Data, base_url().'api/activity/addComment');
                }                
                else
                {
                    @unlink($Data['Media']['attachments']);
                    foreach ($Data['Media']['attachments'] as $attachment)
                    {
                        $i=0;
                        //checkif attachment is there in the response
                        if($attachment['is_attachment'])
                        {
                            //Delete irrelevant data
                            @unlink($attachment['filepath']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           echo 'Done'; 
        }
        else            
            echo 'comments not found!';
        die;        
    }
```

Comment: If you're using imap, then this is always a "pull"/"poll" - meaning you have to regularly ask if there is new mail -  what you apparently want is a "push", meaning, the server tells you that there's new mail. As I said, imap is always pull. So I'd say no to your question. Using a cron is pretty okay!

Comment: ok so is there any alternative of imap in which I can use "push" instead of "pull" ?

Comment: I believe pop3 is pull too and honestly I don't know any other protocoll. Well technically, depending on your mail provider, there technically could be triggers available that do anything. But the technical possibility doesn't imply, that the mail provider actually gives you that option ... and he probably shouldn't. Somewhat of Pandora's box.

Comment: ok thanks for explaining :)

Comment: The question is: How do you expect to be notified about a new mail anyway? Have the browser open? Have an app that tells you? Those are very likely to do a regular pull as well (because it's the sensible thing to do). When they poll your server, that could trigger a poll of the mail server. I don't see the benefit of a push from the mail provider in any case.

Comment: actually what I'm trying to do is when user reply on email it will update as comment on my site but for every new mail I've to check with cron

Comment: I would highly suggest a cronjob. The alternative in your case would be, to check on each page access. Those can be extremely frequent, especially in a (D)DoS attack, in that case, you would DoS/spam your mail provider. Alternatively, you could implement a "cooldown" for the mail retrieval and really fetch mail on page accesses unless a fetch was made < n seconds ago. But seriously, stick with the cron (or a "daemon" which would replace the cron but work exactly the same way in the end)

Comment: IMAP does have a push mode: it is called IDLE.  However the php libraries don't support it, and it requires a long lived process to hold a socket open, which is not usually how PHP is used.  If you're open to other technologies, you could build a python/java/c# app to monitor email for you.  Or build your SMTP server to automatically run a script to put things in a databases for you.  There are many many alternative solutions.

Comment: I know only php :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use external services if you need only to actually receive callback on received email and it doesn't matter to use some specific domain.
For example, you can use ProxiedMail - generate a unique proxy email there and set up a webhook URL to your web page where you want to handle it.